# Vertx append to file

Tags: java, vert.x

How to append data to the end of the file (or to the beginning)? I tried to use

```
list.forEach(str -> {
    vertx.fileSystem().writeFile(path,
        Buffer.buffer(str), result -> {
          if (result.succeeded()) {
            LOGGER.debug(str + " appended");
          } else {
            LOGGER.error(str + " not appended");
          }
        });
  });
```

but it writes only last item.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're overwriting the data with each successive call to `writeFile`, which is why in the file you see only the last item. To append each data item to the file, open the file with [`OpenOptions#setAppend(true)`](http://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/core/file/OpenOptions.html#setAppend-boolean-):

```
vertx.fileSystem().open(path, new OpenOptions().setAppend(true), ar -> {
  if (ar.succeeded()) {
    AsyncFile ws = ar.result();
    list.forEach(str -> {
      Buffer chunk = Buffer.buffer(str);
      ws.write(chunk);
    });
  } else {
    System.err.println("Could not open file");
  }
});
```